# SQL Server 2008 CONVERT statement in VIEW makes the data type NULL in column definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my example view (contrived I know but shows my problem):

```
CREATE VIEW NullTest
AS
SELECT
    1 AS IntNoConvert, 
    CONVERT(BIT, 1) AS IntConvert, 
    CAST(1 AS BIT) AS IntCast
```

The final views as the data types as:

```
IntNoConvert (int, not null)
IntConvert (bit, null)
IntCast (bit null)
```

So the CONVERT and CAST make the column allow NULLs - not normally a problem in views but am I am using LinqToSql ontop of this, I need the datatypes to be NOT NULL.

Any ideas how to make the CONVERT statement return the data as NOT NULL?

Comment: Can't you just change nullable property in your model ?

Comment: Yes I can, I just wanted the DB and the model to match as I have found LinqToSql has some strange output if the NULL/NOT NULL settings don't match up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SQL [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function to ensure non-nullability:

```
CREATE VIEW NullTest
AS
SELECT
    1 AS IntNoConvert, 
    IsNull(CONVERT(BIT, 1), 1) AS IntConvert, 
    IsNull(CAST(1 AS BIT), 1) AS IntCast
```

This feels a little hacky so I agree with a1ex07's comment that you should define the non-nullability in your model instead.

Comment: Thanks this does the trick and the columns are now NOT NULL which is what I wanted.